# What is the time unit used in Oozie retry-interval

Tags: hadoop, oozie

When setting the configuration for Oozie action there is the possibility for allowing a maximum number `retry-max` of retries and Oozie will perform retries after a pre-defined time `retry-interval`. 
In the Oozie documentation I can't find what time-unit is used for this interval. Is it seconds/minutes/...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Source: [User-Retry for Workflow Actions](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a18_User-Retry_for_Workflow_Actions_since_Oozie_3.1)

> Since Oozie 4.3, User-retry allows user to mention retry policy. The value for policy can be periodic or exponential , periodic being the default. Oozie administrator can define user retry policy for all workflow actions by adding this configuration oozie.service.LiteWorkflowStoreService.user.retry.policy to oozie.site.xml . This value will be considered as user retry policy after system restart. This value can be overridden while defining actions in workflow xml if needed. The `retry-interval` should be specified in `minutes`.

Comment: Wow thanks. I have no idea how I just missed that last sentence